# Authentication failed while enabling touch ID

Tags: macos, touch-id

I have deleted the stored fingerprints in touch ID under System Preferences > Touch ID.

Now whenever I want to add a new fingerprint, a popup appears saying "Authentication cancelled."

I only updated the system one day before this to macOS Monterey version (12.0.1)

[image: Screenshot of Touch ID System Preferences showing "Authentication cancelled."]

Answer (score 2):

This solution worked for me (MBP 13" 2017) since I have a T1 chip. Newer macs, this will erase all data.

### Note that following these instructions on a Mac with the T2 chip will require a full restore from a recent backup.

- reboot in Recovery Mode (hold <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> until Apple logo shows up)
- open **Utilities** > **Terminal** in the Recovery Console
- type in

  `xartutil --erase-all`
- "Yes" to erase all entries
- reboot and try to set up TouchID from scratch in System Preferences

Original source on how to reset TouchID: https://eshop.macsales.com/blog/45469-quick-tip-clearing-touch-id-data-from-a-macbook-pro/

If you are concerned about your data or don’t know if you have a T1 or T2 chip, making a backup before using recovery boot and command line “fixes” is always a good idea.

Comment: This worked for me... Thanks @agarza!

Answer (score 1):

Please don't run the above suggestion (`xartutil --erase-all`) on M1 MacBooks; it can require a restore or revive operation of something else goes wrong.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/mac/comments/jye9c0/psa_t2chip_macs_dont_erase_fingerprint_settings/
- https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/macbook-pro-m1-2020-bricked-help.2334900/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  When you say “brick” what is the symptom? Does it start to boot and not complete? https://eclecticlight.co/2022/04/02/explainer-the-bricked-mac/  this process does erase all data, so that warning is clear in the above answer

Answer (score 0):

I first tried the "xartutil" function on a M1 Mackbook Air, which essentially caused the computer to fail to boot up.  It would keep rebooting itself during start up (the progress bar never completes).  In the end it would give me an error saying to go to "support.apple.com/mac/restore."  In other words, please do not use the "xartutil" function with an M1 Mac!

To fix the problem, I had to put the computer into DFU mode first and then do a "Restore" to fix the problem. I tried "Revive" first but that didn't work.  Make sure that the words "DFU" shows up on Apple Configurator before you try to "Restore" or it will fail. It is probably easiest to watch a YouTube video on how to put the computer into DFU mode as it's not straight forward. Warning - This will erase the entire contents of the hard drive.

In regards to the Touch ID problem, I read elsewhere that you had to reset the keychain.  Not sure if this works as I ended up reinstalling my whole computer instead.